# LOGIN CON PRIVILEGIO PHP PDO NO ME FUNCIONA - ME PUEDEN AYUDAR

Tags: php, pdo, login

Este es el código que falla actualizado, adjunto imagen db
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    include('includes/config.php');
    if($_SESSION['alogin']!=''){
        $_SESSION['alogin']='';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $uname=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        /*1. Modificamos el SELECT dado que sólo interesa una columna*/
        $sql ="SELECT Privilegio FROM admin WHERE UserName=:uname and Password=:password";
        $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query-> bindParam(':uname', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> execute();

        /*2. Usamos fetchColumn en vez de fetchAll y ganamos en rendimiento*/
        $privilegio=$query->fetchColumn();

        /*3. Comparamos ahora usando el valor de $privilegio*/
        if($privilegio)
        {
            /*4. No recuperamos $privilegio, porque ya lo tenemos*/
            $urlPages=array(
                                "Administrador"=>"dashboard.php", 
                                "Medico"=>"../medico/dashboard.php"
                            );
            $url=(isset($urlPages[$privilegio])) ? $urlPages[$privilegio] : NULL;
            if($url){                                
                header("Location: $url");
            }else{
                 echo "La clave $privilegio no tiene URL asociada";   
            }

        }else{
            echo "Los datos introducidos son erroneos";
        }
    }
?>
```

---

actualmente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] tengo el código de la siguiente manera

{

prepare($sql);
        $query-> bindParam(':uname', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> execute();

        /*2. Usamos fetchColumn en vez de fetchAll y ganamos en rendimiento*/
        $privilegio=$query->fetchColumn();

        /*3. Comparamos ahora usando el valor de $privilegio*/
        if($privilegio)
        {
            /*4. No recuperamos $privilegio, porque ya lo tenemos*/
            $urlPages=array(
                                "Administrador"=>"dashboard.php", 
                                "Medico"=>"../medico/dashboard.php"
                            );
            $url=(isset($urlPages[$privilegio])) ? $urlPages[$privilegio] : NULL;
            if($url){                                
                header("Location: $url");
            }else{
                 echo "La clave $privilegio no tiene URL asociada";   
            }

        }else{
            echo "Los datos introducidos son erroneos";
        }
    }
?>

}

Comment: Bienvenido. Para futuras preguntas considera identar el código. Cuando lo pegues, lo seleccionas todo y luego pulsas sobre los símbolos **`{   }`** que aparecen en la parte superior. En cuanto la pregunta, ¿dónde está el valor de la variable **`$privilegio`** en tu contexto?

Comment: como paso el valor de esa variable ??

Comment: Eso eres tú quien debe saberlo. ¿Ese valor viene del mismo sitio que `username` y `password`?  Si así fuera y el `name` del input es `privilegio`, tendrías que hacer algo parecido a lo que haces con las otras: `$privilegio=$_POST['privilegio'];` Si no es así, haz un `print_r($_POST);` para ver todo lo que estás recibiendo en el POST, ahí estará el nombre de cada clave y su valor.

Comment: Los privilegios los llamo mediante una consulta sql a la base de datos , el usuario que se golea no introduce ningún datos referido al privilegio

Comment: Eso lo entiendo perfectamente, pero si quieres filtrar por privilegio debes conocer ese valor antes, o quitarlo del `WHERE`.  Pregunto, ¿por qué lo tienes en el `WHERE` si no conoces ese valor?

Comment: plo pongo eb el where para que me filtre si es usuario es admin o empleado

Comment: que me recomiendas que lo saque del where

Comment: Yo lo que veo es que tu código no es lógico. Veo que intentas traer datos filtrando por privilegio y luego comparas con una variable de sesión para determinar el privilegio. Es o una u otra: si filtras por privilegio usando el `WHERE` debes conocer antes por qué privilegio quieres filtrar; si filtras posteriormente, traes el privilegio y otros datos que quieras filtrados por usuario y password, y luego comparas con la variable de sesión (creo que es esto último lo que quieres hacer). Aunque tampoco te has tomado el tiempo de explicar siquiera un poco lo que intentas hacer...

Comment: Además, en las comparaciones posteriores no usas para nada los datos que traes de la base de datos... ¿para qué consultas entonces a la base de datos?  Creo que deberías editar la pregunta, explicando con claridad lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Te comento, yo tengo el login arriba mostrado funcionado normalmente sin filtrar por privilegios, lo que necesito es modificarlo para que me rediriga el usuario segun su nivel de acceso a una pagina u otra , es decir esto es una programa sobre medicina , yo quiero que cuando el medico haga login se le redigira a el dashboard asignado a el (dashboard_medico.php)

Comment: Según entiendo, tendrías que quitar `privilegio` del `WHERE` (**no del `SELECT`**) y quitarlo también del `bindParam`, recuperarlo después del `fetchAll` haciendo algo como esto: `$privilegio=$results->privilegio;`  y luego comparar así: `if($privilegio == 'Administrador')`  y también aquí:  `elseif($privilegio == 'Empleado')`

Comment: E modificado el login arriba de ejemplo y e puesto el original que me funciona correctamente, necesito modifcar ese para que me filtre por los privilegios

Comment: Se puede saber porqué todo el rato quitas el formato de código de tu pregunta? Si es código se representa como código, ya que se estructura bien y se entiende todo a la primera. Si le quitas el formato de código aparece todo en una línea y no se entiende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que buscar el dato relativo a `privilegio` en la base de datos incluyéndolo en el `SELECT`, y luego comparar el valor de esa columna:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    include('includes/config.php');
    if($_SESSION['alogin']!=''){
        $_SESSION['alogin']='';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $uname=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        /*1. Modificamos el SELECT dado que sólo interesa una columna*/
        $sql ="SELECT Privilegio FROM admin WHERE UserName=:uname and Password=:password";
        $query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
        $query-> bindParam(':uname', $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query-> execute();

        /*2. Usamos fetchColumn en vez de fetchAll y ganamos en rendimiento*/
        $privilegio=$query->fetchColumn();

        /*3. Comparamos ahora usando el valor de $privilegio*/
        if($privilegio)
        {
            /*4. Ya no recuperamos $privilegio, porque ya lo tenemos*/
            $urlPages=array(
                                "Administrador"=>"dashboard.php", 
                                "Medico"=>"../medico/dashboard.php"
                            );
            $url=(isset($urlPages[$privilegio])) ? $urlPages[$privilegio] : NULL;
            if($url){                                
                header("Location: $url");
            }else{
                 echo "La clave $privilegio no tiene URL asociada";   
            }

        }else{
            echo "Los datos introducidos son erroneos";
        }
    }
?>
```

**NOTAS:**

- He asumido que la columna en la BD se llama `Privilegio`
- Di si el código funciona. Si no funciona di si muestra algo el `var_dump` que he puesto. Luego debo sugerirte algunas mejoras en tu código...

Comment: no me funcional el código que me has puesto , te comento que has aceptado en el codigo privilegio pero cuando le pongo  para que redirecciones no hace absolutamente nada

Comment: me da el siguiente error Otro privilegio. Hacer lo que quieras....array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["UserName"]=> string(13) "ADMINISTRADOR" ["Password"]=> string(32) "4f416421a0d6f01991bff3408b8bb303" ["Privilegio"]=> string(13) "Administrador" } }

Comment: No es un error, entra ahí porque arriba hemos hecho esta comparación: `if ($privilegio=="Empleado"){`  si lo cambias por `if ($privilegio=="Administrador"){` te entrará en la primera parte del `if`... porque como se puede ver en el `var_dump`, privilegio tiene el valor de Administrador: `["Privilegio"]=> string(13) "Administrador"`. No sé si me explico, @YandryHernandez. El código funciona bien, ahora hay que mejorarlo, poniendo todas las comparaciones que sean necesarias.  Dime qué redirecciones quieres hacer y cómo se llaman las páginas y te completo la respuesta.

Comment: Quiero que si es Administrador rediriga a: dashboard.php y si es medico a ../medico/dashboard.php - gracias por la ayuda